# fixed width of column in csv mode

Tags: csv

I plan to use `csv-mode`. In Excel, csv can be shown like the Picture 2. In emacs, `C-c C-a` yields Picture 1. Can I fix the width of the columns in `csv-mode`?

Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: You can use Org mode tables to do that. I don't know if csv-mode does that. Also, what is `C-c C-a` bound to in your case? It is undefined for me, so I'm wondering if there is more than one csv-mode. The one that I have is from  https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/csv-mode.html.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following setting solve this issue.

```
(use-package csv-mode
  :config
  (setq csv-align-max-width 7)
  (define-key csv-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-a") 'csv-align-mode))
```